# Usando o phonegap build, alguém conseguiu implementar vídeo no android?

Tags: apache-cordova, build

Tenho usado o phonegap build com o plugin "nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus" captura de vídeo. Ele captura normalmente no android e ios, porém tem 2 problemas:

1 - No android não consigo achar o caminho do arquivo, portanto não consigo fazer upload usando o plugin "org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"

2 - Os vídeos capturados no iphone 5c sobem pro servidor e tocam normalmente com a tag de vídeo do html5. porém os vídeos do iphone6 não funcionam.

Estou usando o phonegap build na versão 3.7.0

Alguém já teve esses problemas?? como resolveu??